# Strange linking error that occurs only on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, singleton, linker-errors

So, I have a interface library, that contains single singleton class and another class that is using it.

Let's say that it contains following code:

`signleton.h`

```cpp
struct Singleton {}; //< Singleton (actually it is in different file, but it really doesn't matter)

struct Object
{
public:
    using Instance = std::pair<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<Singleton>>;

    template <typename T>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> makeSingleton(T value)
    {
        inst = std::make_pair(typeid(T).hash_code(), std::make_shared<T>(value));
        return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(inst.second);
    }
private: 
    static Instance inst;
};
```

Also I have 2 places where I want to use it:

- `main.cpp`
- `some_other_file.cpp`

Basically, `main.cpp` is an executable, and `some_other_file.cpp` is another library that is linked to `main.cpp` executable, so the structure looks like that:

`main.cpp` contains library with `some_other_file.cpp` that contains interface 'signleton.h'

When I try to create static instance of `Object::Instance` in `main.cpp`, on MacOS (on other systems everything works fine) I get linking error.

Error:

```
Undefined symbol for architecture x86_64:
    "Object::Instance", referenced from:
        some_function_where_it_is_used() in some_other_file.cpp
        ...
```

I'm using old macbook air from 2016 so it's not M1 related issue.

I was able to solve this issue by moving `Object::Instance` to `some_other_file.cpp`, but as I want to make this thing easier to find, I want to keep it in `main.cpp`.

Also I never had figured out the main cause of this issue, I guess it's something about linking order and stuff, but I'm not really sure, cause it occurs only on MacOS.

Comment: What C++ version are you on?
I'd either use `static inline Instance inst;` (17 onwards) or just initialize `inst` in a totally separate file. Or you can replace `inst` with a static getter returning a static variable inside of it.

Comment: @alagner I’m on cpp 20

Comment: then I'd make it inline and remove initialization from .cpp if possible :)

Comment: Could it be the order you link the files in? Link order matters for some linkers.

Comment: @ jesper-juhl Yeah, I thought about linking order, but wasn't able to find any information, that would prove this theory :/

Answer (score 0):

macOS binary executables must be dynamically linked.  The operating system and tool chain simply does not support the static build of an executable.

Binary executable may be dynamically linked to a statically built library.

Except for kernel extensions, but they won’t rely on anything as they are self-standing blocks.

Cf. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706419